# Python trivia game

Tags: python

I want to make a trivia game using 2 arrays or lists. How do you link items from one list to another?  I have this code:

```
import random

mylist = ['A','B','C']
answer = ['1','2','3']
value = random.choice(mylist)
print (value)
input()
mylist.remove(value)
value = random.choice(mylist)
mylist.remove(value)
print (value)
input()
value = random.choice(mylist)
print(value)
mylist.remove(value)
```

I know how to randomly choose a variable from `mylist` (the questions) but how do I represent A as 1 and have the user input 1 for it to be correct?

How do I link one list to another and make a trivia game? It needs to ask a question and then the user inputs answer. If correct, they get a point and after 4 questions it asks them if they want to play again and then 4 new questions for 3 rounds and there has to be a score kept of how many they got right.

Comment: Ok so i tried that and it gave me a syntax error about ask what does that do and how can i fix this?

Comment: Ok one last thing, how with this set up would you have the option to play again? so lets say i add 10 or 15 questions and in the first game you have 4 questions ask then it will ask you if you want to play again and then have 4 new questions ask! also how do you make it so those never repeat like remove the can you use the questions.remove(Question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program is right on the borderline between being acceptable as a list/dict of lists and being better off written with classes.  If there's any possibility that it will grow, you'd probably want to reorganize it as an object oriented program (OOP), like this:

```
import sys
import random

class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, question, answer, options):
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options

    def ask(self):
        print self.question + "?"
        for n, option in enumerate(self.options):
            print "%d) %s" % (n + 1, option)

        response = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())   # answers are integers
        if response == self.answer:
            print "CORRECT"
        else:
            print "wrong"

questions = [
    Question("How many legs on a horse", 4, ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]),
    Question("How many wheels on a bicycle", 2, ["one", "two", "three", "twenty-six"]),

    # more verbose formatting
    Question(question="What colour is a swan in Australia",
             answer=1,
             options=["black", "white", "pink"]),    # the last one can have a comma, too
    ]

random.shuffle(questions)    # randomizes the order of the questions

for question in questions:
    question.ask()
```

That puts the logic of how the data structure is used closer to where the data structure is defined.  Also (addressing your original question), it's easy to associate questions with answers because they're no longer in separate lists.

There's no incentive not to do this because Python doesn't require much extra work to make a class.  This is approximately the same length as the dict-of-lists solution (on which it was based), and is arguably easier to read, closer to you had in mind before you sat down to start programming.  I often use classes even in four-line programs: OOP doesn't have to be a big deal.

**Edit:** You can manipulate the list of class instances the same way you'd manipulate a list of integers or strings.  For example,

```
del questions[0]
```

removes the first item from the list,

```
questions.append(Question("What is a new question", 1, ["This is."]))
```

adds a new question to the end of the list, `pop` lets you use the list as a stack, etc.  (See a Python tutorial for more.)  If you want to remove specific questions using list's `remove` method, rather than removing it by index (what `del` does), then you'll need to tell Python what it means for two questions to be the same.

Try adding these two methods to the class:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.question == other.question

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Question: %s? at %0x>" % (self.question, id(self))
```

The first defines two `Question` instances to be equal if their question strings are the same.  You could extend the definition by also requiring their answers to be the same, but you get the idea.  It allows you to do this:

```
questions.remove(Question("How many legs on a horse", 0, []))
```

to remove the legs-on-a-horse question.

The second pretty-prints the question objects on the Python command-line, so that you can see what you're doing when you experiment with these commands.  The best way to learn is by trial-and-error, and this makes trial-and-error more productive.

Comment: You are amazing thanks soo much i am so gladd for this you have no idea

Comment: Ok one last thing, how with this set up would you have the option to play again? so lets say i add 10 or 15 questions and in the first game you have 4 questions ask then it will ask you if you want to play again and then have 4 new questions ask! also how do you make it so those never repeat like remove the can you use the questions.remove(Question)

Comment: Note that `random.shuffle` randomizes the order, so that when you go through the randomized list once, there will be no repeats.  In general, it's much easier to handle the no-repeats problem with a shuffled list than by adding and removing items from the list.

Comment: Ok almost got everything figured out what i am confused now is how do you like lets say you have 20question in the game and you want to do 4 questions and ask some one if they want to continue playing and if yes it will ask more questions and if no then it will exit the game? any ideas i was thing the playagain option but i cant figure out how to define it

Comment: Shuffle the 20 questions, ask 4 questions (with something like `for question in questions[0:4]`), ask if the user wants to keep playing, and if so, ask the next 4 questions (with `for question in questions[4:8]`).

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of arrays.

One array per question

In each array the first element is the question, the second the index of the correct answer and the remainder are the possible answer options

I have not randomized the questions as you can already do this

```
import sys

questions=[
  ['How many legs on a horse',4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5],
  ['How many wheels on a bicycle',2,'one','two','three','twenty six'],
  ['What colour is a swan in Australia',1, 'black', 'white', 'pink']
  ]

for ask in questions:
    print ask[0]+'?'
    n = 1
    for options in ask[2:]:
        print "%d) %s" % (n,options)
        n = n + 1
    response = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if int(response) == ask[1]:
        print "CORRECT"
    else:
        print "wrong"
```

Alternatively, in line with suggestion below in comments (thanks Don) use a dict.

```
import sys

questions = [
  {
  'question': 'How many legs on a horse',
  'answer': 4,
  'options': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
  {
   'question': 'How many wheels on a bicycle',
   'answer': 2,
   'options': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'twenty six']},

  {
   'question': 'What colour is a swan in Australia',
   'answer': 1,
   'options': ['black', 'white', 'pink']}
  ]

for ask in questions:
    print ask['question'] + '?'
    n = 1
    for options in ask['options']:
        print "%d) %s" % (n, options)
        n = n + 1
    response = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if int(response) == ask['answer']:
        print "CORRECT"
    else:
        print "wrong"
```

hope this helps

Comment: dictionary are a better choice, as they can give a meaning to each 'element' of the question

Comment: e.g. questions = ({'q': 'How many legs...', 'choices'=[1,2,3,4,5], 'correct':4}, {'q': 'Home many wheels...', ... ...

Comment: Ok for some reason i am getting an error with ask keeps saying invalid syntex

Comment: On using 'n = n + 1' - you can use enumerate for that: for n, options in enumerate(ask[2:], 1):

Comment: If you get a syntax error then start a new question with the code, the exact syntax error message and a description of what you have done to fix it